# Is there a way to access a user's submitted LinkedIn applications?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm wanting to pull the data (title, company, date applied, etc) for the jobs I've applied to on LinkedIn but I can't find anything in the API docs. Is there something I'm missing? Is this data available programmatically or only via the GUI?